# Can we install TimescaleDB as a postgres extension on AWS RDS for postgres?

Tags: timescaledb

A naive question on RDS:  TimescaleDB acts as a postgres extension. As an AWS user, can I install TimescaleDB as a postgres extension on AWS RDS for postgres?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

TimescaleDB is not available through AWS RDS.

Further, TimescaleDB's licensing [0] means that Amazon cannot offer the "community" version of TimescaleDB that includes many of its advanced features.  Timescale (the company) does offer a fully-managed cloud on AWS, however. [1]

(Timescale person here)

[0] https://blog.timescale.com/blog/building-open-source-business-in-cloud-era-v2/

[1] https://www.timescale.com/products

Comment: Thank you Mike!  My question is more about the feasibility of installing TimescaleDB extension on AWS RDS. Is this feasible?

Comment: AWS RDS does not allow you to "install" extensions yourself; the only ones are available are those that come pre-installed.

Answer (score 0):

We tried the same thing, then realized timescale db is not within the list of available extensions in RDS.

Though we did manage to do it within a self hosted version of psql via ec2.